# How to find out which interfaces a .net class implements?

Tags: c#, .net

Ok, so I've been learning c# and .net recently and one thing that seems to be missing from the c# documentation on http://msdn.microsoft.com/ that is present in the java documentation (e.g. [ArrayList doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) is that a java class's documentation will say something like:

> All Implemented Interfaces: Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable,
>   Collection, List, RandomAccess Direct Known Subclasses:
>   AttributeList, RoleList, RoleUnresolvedList

This allows me to find out which interfaces it implements and possibly discover interfaces I didn't know of yet. I can further click on an interface and get information on which classes implement it (in the standard classes anyway) and which interfaces extend it:

```
All Superinterfaces:
     Iterable<E>
All Known Subinterfaces:
     BeanContext, BeanContextServices, BlockingDeque<E>, BlockingQueue<E>, ...
All Known Implementing Classes:
     AbstractCollection, AbstractList, AbstractQueue, AbstractSequentialList, ...
```

When using Microsoft's documentation I only get the base classes and possibly subclasses:

```
System.Object 
  System.MarshalByRefObject
    System.IO.Stream
      More...
```

"More..." being a link with a list of subclasses.

Is there a way in the documentation to find what interfaces a .Net class implements in a similar way that we can in the Java documentation?

Edit: I'm using Visual Studio Express and the publicly available documentation on MSDN so I suppose that the answer might be: yes you can, but you must pay up first for [full visual studio|MSDN subscription|...].

Comment: I doubt this is the right place to ask such question.

Comment: Also i dont quite get your question. Check the documentation on list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx . THere is a list of all interfaces in the class declaration `public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable`

Comment: "THere is a list of all interfaces in the class declaration". Indeed, but looking at its subclass [DataServiceCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474331.aspx) it is not mentioned there. So apparently one way is to look at a class's base classes and see what they implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Documentation**

Check out the **Syntax** section (e.g. for [IObservableCollection(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)) in the documentation.

This gives the class declaration, including implemented interfaces

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, 
    INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

**ILSpy**

However, for classes for which documentation is not available, you can use a dissassembler such as [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). Simply select a class, and it will show all base-types and derived types.
[image]

**Object Browser**
Finally, you can also use the Object Browser in Visual Studio (I'm not 100% sure it's in Express). **View** → **Object Browser**. This will show the base-types as you require.

[image]

Comment: The object browser method works very well, thank you. I haven't tried the ILSpy method yet but thanks for the information. One caveat with the syntax section is that apparently it only mentions interfaces that this class implements at that level so that if a base class implements an interface it appears in that base class's syntax section but not in derived classes syntax section, which is what threw me off.

Comment: @JulienRousseau If that's your concern, then ILSpy or Object Browser is for you - they both show a tree of the inheritance tree, as shown in the screenshots in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, place the caret on the thing you want to know about e.g. `bool` and press <kbd>F12</kbd>

It will show you the definition of the thing you pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> on, so for `bool`:

```
namespace System
{
    // Summary:
    //     Represents a Boolean value.
    [Serializable]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public struct Boolean : IComparable, IConvertible, IComparable<bool>, IEquatable<bool>
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Represents the Boolean value false as a string. This field is read-only.
        public static readonly string FalseString;
...
```

---

Additionally you can open the **Code Definition Window** (View>Code Definition Window, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>) which will show the above in a window - no button presses needed!

Comment: Note that the the Code Definition Window stopped working in VS2015, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718303/code-definition-window-not-working-in-vs2015

Answer (score 0):

Resharper has a feature that allows that as well. If you press Ctrl+Shift+F1 then you can see a documentation about the class with full list of interfaces that it implements. You can decompile it using resharper to achieve the same result (though it's a little bit too much for what you need).

Answer (score 0):

Resharper has [Go to Base Symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Base.html). you can use:

- `CTRL + U`
- Right click the class name > Navigate > Base Symbols
- Resharper menu > Navigate > Base Symbols

> This command allows you to navigate up the inheritance hierarchy to a
>   base type [including classes and interfaces] or method of the current symbol.

Here's a sample from a XAML.cs file

[image]