# Code Definition Window not working in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Just upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and the Code Definition Window is not working.It just says "No definition selected" no matter what I select. Project is Windows Forms written in C#.

- Go to Definition and Peek Definition are working fine
- Went back to VS2013 to try it out and it's still working there
- Tried to make a brand new project in VS2015 to see if it was project related, but it was not
- Checked with a couple of colleagues and it wasn't working for them either

I have a feeling this is either a bug in VS2015 or some sort of configuration change.

Anyone found a way to configure it, or any sort of work around to get it up and running again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they just merged a fix for this into Roslyn:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/56102

Answer (score 14):

I got a reply from Microsoft on my Bug report. Turns out it's not implemented and possibly never will be:

> Hi,
>
> Based on the fact that Peek Definition was introduced in VS2013,
>   combined with telemetry data that shows that only a tiny percentage of
>   users ever display the Code Definition Window, we decided not to
>   implement support for it as part of Roslyn. I've filed an issue on our
>   GitHub project to consider resurrecting it.
>
> Thanks for the report!
>   -- Kevin Pilch-Bisson Visual Studio Managed Languages

Here´s the github issue Kevin created in response to my bug report in July: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4224

Comment: Darn. We use that a lot during code reviews (for obvious reasons).

Comment: This was probably THE most productive feature of Visual Studio. I've got one of my five monitors dedicated only to the Code Definition Window. With the Peek Definition I can't even move the popup window to another monitor. Definitely going back to VS 2013.

Comment: I also use it all the time.... ridiculous. Do you have a link to the GitHub item so we can voice our support for getting it added back?

Comment: Are we talking about the "ALT-F12" peek definition then it's still working for me

Comment: It might be nice if they removed the Code Definition Window selection from the View menu, and removed the shortcut key;  being able to open a non-working window is goofy.

Comment: 2 years later and its still possible to open that window without it working as intended (which is what led me here). I cant believe the amount of money they are charging for this piece of software...