# Now that VS2015 has dropped support for the code definition window are there any alternatives?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

MS has [dropped support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718303/code-definition-window-not-working-in-vs2015) for the code definition window with Roslyn.

I already have R# installed and don't want to install CodeRush as well to get this functionality back.

Has anyone seen a (free) plugin that does this and preferably only this? Peek does not fit with my workflow (as also stated in the mentioned post)

Comment: If you mean the "ALT-F12" peek definition then it's still working for me

Comment: @PaulCarroll I don't want to use Alt-Peek as I cannot dock it anywhere and it does not work as well as Code Definition especially when doing code reviews.

Comment: Fair enough. I also wondered after I posted that comment if it was a R# feature I was using anyway.. the lines get blurry these days  :)

Comment: @PaulCarroll Yeah they do.... I just cannot believe the window is still there if they actually were not supporting it. Really dumb. Hopefully someone has a solution somewhere.

Comment: I have submitted a feature request to JetBrains to add this to R#.