# Getting all interfaces of a C# class in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to get a list of all interfaces of a C# class in the Visual Studio UI without digging through the superclass chain step by step? If not even a list on MSDN would be useful.

For example I can't see that [`Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx) is `IDisposable` without digging down to [`Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This is what I was thinking, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17447597/495455 - also see the ReSharper answer if you want to do it inside Visual Studio

Comment: Turns out, it's quite easy with reflection, if that helps: `typeof(List<int>).FindInterfaces((t, o) => true, null)`.

Comment: OP Can you clarify that you mean via the Visual Studio UI? I've seen a couple of answers (one now deleted) that involve reflection.

Comment: @john: yes via the UI preferably

Comment: I'm not sure why a coder would need a pointy-clicky way to do this, but OK...

Answer (score 0):

GetInterfaces:
`typeof(List<string>).GetInterfaces()`
returns

`Type[] (8 items)4 
typeof(IList<String>) 
typeof(ICollection<String>) 
typeof(IEnumerable<String>) 
typeof(IEnumerable) 
typeof(IList) 
typeof(ICollection) 
typeof(IReadOnlyList<String>) 
typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<String>)`

If you need to know a particular interface,  you can use IsAssignableFrom:

`typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<string>))`

returns `true`

Comment: ...and from the UI?

Comment: I just meant that it was apparent from the question (even before the edit) that it was asking for a UI way of doing it, not a code way of doing it.

Comment: The UI has an "Immediate" window where you can run short code snippets like this.  Or use a watch expression

Comment: In the 2017 version (maybe came out in 2015) there is a "C# Interactive" window that can make this very easy. The benefit of this being it doesn't require you to compile you application, like the "Immediate" windows does.

I just verified, this *does* crawl all the way up the stack and show all Interfaces implemented by this class and any superclass.